# Backstage.io: How to place node at specific position in the dependency graph on UI

Tags: nodes, backstage

is there a way how to place node at specific position in the dependency graph on UI in Backstage.io framework? I need to place ownership entities at right upper corner of the graph (see the red frame in the picture).[ER diagram on UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Esw.png)

I have defined type RelationPairs = [string,string][] in which custom relations are defined as const ALL_REL_PAIRS: RelationPairs = [[REL_OWNER_OF, REL_OWNED_BY], ...]